# How to frame joining conditions while joining on multiple columns?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, dbt

I'm trying to join the 2 tables below on multiple columns (on big query through dbt cloud).

*t1 as*

| id | 2021_code | 2022_code | 2023_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P | 1 |  |  |
| Q | 2 | 3 |  |
| R | 4 | 5 | 6 |

*t2 as*

| code | label |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | E |
| 6 | F |

For each non-null value in the last three columns in t1, I want to have a distinct row with a unique label in the joined table.

I'm expecting the below joined table.

| id | code | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P | 1 | A |
| Q | 2 | B |
| Q | 3 | C |
| R | 4 | D |
| R | 5 | E |
| R | 6 | F |

I've tried the following code but have understandably failed.

*select id, code, label from t1 left join t2 on 2021_code = code or 2022_code = code or 2023_code = code*

My join condition or approach clearly needs revision. Will be grateful for any inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recreate t1 to make 1 code column and then join

```
SELECT
  t1.id, t1.code,t2.label
FROM (
  SELECT id, 2021_code AS code FROM t1 WHERE 2021_code IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, 2022_code AS code FROM t1 WHERE 2022_code IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, 2023_code AS code FROM t1 WHERE 2023_code IS NOT NULL
) t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.code = t2.code
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `JOIN` the tables on the desired column each time and `UNION ALL` the results.

```
SELECT
    Id, 
    code,
    label
FROM t1

    JOIN t2 
        ON code = 2021_code

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Id, 
    code,
    label
FROM t1

    JOIN t2 
        ON code = 2022_code

UNION ALL

SELECT
    Id, 
    code,
    label
FROM t1

    JOIN t2 
        ON code = 2023_code
```

The code is for MS SQL, but I'm sure you can easily apply the method to Big query. See the [DB Fiddle for results](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/275w4hjADsfwBTt9XfHCAG/0).

Comment: Thanks! Both queries work. I have a high number of columns which makes the second query with multiple joins a little expensive. The first one however works perfectly. Grateful to both respondents for teaching.